# Is there a way to set a "new" parameter, internally to a template or other page?

Tags: mediawiki

Let's say I have some page which can take two parameters, x and y. I often find myself doing things in that page like in this silly little example:

```
{{#if: {{{x|{{{y|}}}}}} | '''{{{x|{{{y|}}}}}}'''. I repeat, {{{x|{{{y|}}}}}}.}}
```

In many cases, I would greatly prefer to simplify the reuse of `{{{x|{{{y|}}}}}}`, for clarity, for ease of typing, and for making it more difficult to miss or to screw up. So, I'd like to do something like the following hypothetical syntax:

```
{{#set:z|{{{x|{{{y|}}}}}}}}
{{#if: {{{z|}}} | '''{{{z}}}'''. I repeat, {{{z}}}.}}
```

That is, make a new parameter, z, which was *not* passed to the page, but nonetheless can be used in the page. Is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the extension [Variables](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Variables), but it assumes a certain order of parsing, which will not be the case when pages are parsed with Parsoid.

To guarantee the right order of parsing you can use [Lua](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto).

But the simplest way will be to create a new template, taking only one parameter and to call it from the original one.

`Template1`:

```
{{template2| z = {{{x|{{{y|}}}}}} }}
```

`Template2`:

```
{{#if: {{{z}}} | '''{{{z}}}'''. I repeat, {{{z}}}.}}
```